# ShadowCopy Error 7001 (Unable to create a shadow copy) but SC got created and works fine, what to do?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-attached-storage, iscsi, vss

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2 on a Dell R410. A QNAP NAS is connected to it via gigabit crossover.  A 2.6 TB LUN is mounted via iSCSI as Volume Z:.

A task should create Shadow Copies three times a day (08:00, 12:00 and 16:00).

For every task I got a `VSS Error 7001` (Unable to create a shadow copy) in the Event Viewer, however the Shadow Copies got created and work perfectly fine.

The Error says the selected Volume was not found or is not a local Volume but the Shadow Copy Storage Area is located at the local System Partition.

What should I do? Just ignore these error messages?

[image: Error Message]
[image: VSS copies]

Appendix 04.09.2012:

I got new problems that maybe are associated with the `VSS Error 7001`. The Shadow Copys wont be displayed in the file/folder properties dialog on both, client and server side. In the disc properties on the server i can still see the Shadow Copys. Any advice? I dont want to loose VSS functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't jump to ignoring them right away, but erroneous error messages happen from time to time.

First of all, pardon me, but my German... or Dutch... well, my not-English sucks, but in that error message, it looks like there's a retry on the VSS creation.  Is it possible that the Shadow Copies are initially failing to be created, but are successfully occurring after a retry?  Look for subsequent `informational`-level messages in the `Event Log` that might indicate success.

If there aren't any, and you can't track down why you're getting these errors, I'd do a restore-test, to make sure those Shadow Copies are actually valid and contain your data, and if they do, well, yeah, maybe ignoring the errors is the most efficient use of your time.

Comment: There is no retry. The next info-level event is `VSS Error 8224` (The VSS service is shutting down due to idle timeout.) about 3 and a half minuts later. The Shadow Copie was definitely created by the task that finished with the `VSS Error 7001`. I already did a restore test, it works like a charm ;)

Comment: I got rid of the `VSS Error 7001` by manually deleting the corresponding task in the task sheduler and recreating the `VSS` settings in the properties of the drive. Unfortunately I still got the problems described above: The Shadow Copys still wont be displayed in the file/folder properties dialog on both, client and server side. In the disc properties on the server i can still see the Shadow Copys.

Comment: The Shadow Copys on client and server side showed up again after rebooting the server, everything works smoothly now...